# Как на PHP прочитать содержимое файла, не указывая его расширение?

Tags: php, файлы

Необходимо прочитать текстовый файл .php, .html, .js или txt без указывания его расширения, но известно его неполное имя - "filename.*"

Comment: А как можно определить текстовый файл или нет не зная расширения? Вот если в папке exe лежит или .mp3 или порновидео на 10 Гб, то что?

Comment: А если в каталоге есть и .html, и .php, и .js одновременно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$exts = ['php', 'html', 'js', 'txt'];
foreach(glob('filename.*') as $file)  
{  
    $info = new SplFileInfo($file);
    if(in_array($info->getExtension(), $exts))
    {
       $my_file = file_get_contents($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Только не забудьте `break`.

Comment: @VladD Зачем `break`?

Comment: немного изменил описание

Comment: @player0k Исправил ответ

Comment: @LANSELOT: А зачем крутить цикл по всем файлам, если вы уже нашли нужный?

Comment: @VladD это уже вопрос необходимости (читать все файлы или лишь первый найденный)

Comment: @LANSELOT: Ну, автор в вопросе явно спросил про _один_ файл, у которого не известно расширение. Я отталкивался от этого.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(glob(__DIR__."/filename*.{php,html,js,txt}", GLOB_BRACE) as $file)  
{  
  $contents[] = file_get_contents($file);
}
```

После этого `$contents` будет иметь в себе массив с контентом файлов которые были либо `php` либо `html` либо `js` либо `txt`.

Список будет отформатирован в последовательности нахождения этих файлов в директории.

Comment: Немного изменилось условие - у нас есть не полное имя 1 файла и надо прочитать именно его "filename.*"

Comment: Я изменил ответ. В данном случаи найдет `filename` и любые символы после `filename`. Так же файл будет одним из расширений указанных выше.

Answer (score 1):

Из вопроса не понятно:

- вам надо найти файл зная только имя без расширения? Тогда [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php)
- вам надо открыть и прочитать произвольный файл? тогда [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)